# Signup Auth Will Not Work

Tags: php

When a user signs up you will get an email for a auth link. When you click on the auth link it will just stay blank.

auth.php

```
<?
session_start();
?>

    <? include "includes/dbconfig.php"; ?>
<? if ($_GET[action] == "activate" && $_GET[user] != "" && $_GET[hms] != "") {

$username = $_GET[user];
$authtime = $_GET[hms];

$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND auth='yes'");
         if (mysql_num_rows($check_query) != "0") {
        $error = "Your account has already been activated!";
            } else {
$_SESSION[ipaddress] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET auth='yes' WHERE username='$username'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET authtime='$authtime' WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error());
$_SESSION[membersusername] = $_GET[user];
 echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=http://nn.tv' />";

}   }
?>
```

It use to work but when server people updated PHP to  5.4.34 seems like nothing wants to work no more.

Comment: if it stays blank turn on error reporting.

Comment: Note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they will be removed from PHP in future versions and your code will stop working then. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Comment: I really don't fancy writing it all again in myswli or pdo if I can help it.

Comment: Check basic stuff, like if short_open_tags is enabled? `<?` won't work if the setting's off. Plus, you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). This is ESPECIALLY bad since it's a login script.

Comment: You also have numerous syntax glitches by using unquoted array keys everywhere.

Comment: Change `<?` to `<?php`